# WinUI 2.6 without UWP restrictions?

Tags: c#, winui, windows-11

I want to write an application for Windows 11 (using WinUI 2.6) without all the restrictions of UWP, which seems to be the only way to write apps with WinUI 2.6. The idea is I want to be able to distribute the application on its own instead of in an app package, and I want it to be able to run external programs. I just can't figure out if it's possible, let alone how to do it.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/winui3/desktop-winui3-app-with-basic-interop

Answer (score 2):

Win UI 2.x targets the sandboxed UWP platform.

You should look into [WinUI3](https://microsoft.github.io/microsoft-ui-xaml/about.html) if you want to develop a full-trust desktop application that can run external programs for example.

Answer (score 1):

WinUI 2 is only supported with UWP.
The next iteration of WinUI is [WinUI3](https://microsoft.github.io/microsoft-ui-xaml/about.html) and it uses the same UWP XAML.